# How to draw with python

Tags: python

I have a triangle and want to split it into 2 color, left side color red and the right side color yellow.
I can not.
If you can see my code, run it you see 2 triangles and I want to first want to split. See the picture example:

Here is my code:

```
import turtle

def dreieck(x, y, direction, size, color):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setpos(x, y)
    turtle.setheading(direction)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.left(120)
    turtle.end_fill()

dreieck(100, 200, 180, 200, "red")

turtle.left(120)

turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(-50, -50)
turtle.setheading(180)
turtle.pendown()

dreieck(-100, -150, 0, 200, "blue")
```

Comment: thank you, that means that I have to change the code completey because the code above draw only same triangle size, right ?

Comment: "I can not" -- you probably _can_, you just need to restrategize and [break the problem down differently](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/).

Answer (score 0):

The disconnect I see from the provided illustration is that the problem involves three *isosceles right triangles* but your code draws *equilateral triangles*!  First, we need to change your code to draw the correct type of triangle and then apply it three times from the correct position and orientation.  There are many ways to do this, here's an example:

```
import turtle

MY_HYPOTENUSE = 200
MY_LEG = MY_HYPOTENUSE * 2**0.5/2

def dreieck(hypotenuse, color):
    leg = hypotenuse * 2**0.5/2

    turtle.fillcolor(color)

    turtle.begin_fill()

    turtle.forward(hypotenuse)
    turtle.left(135)
    turtle.forward(leg)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(leg)
    turtle.left(135)

    turtle.end_fill()

dreieck(MY_HYPOTENUSE, 'blue')

turtle.left(45)

turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(2 * MY_LEG)
turtle.pendown()

turtle.left(135)

dreieck(MY_HYPOTENUSE, 'green')

turtle.right(135)
turtle.backward(MY_LEG)

dreieck(MY_LEG, 'red')

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

There are likely more clever and efficient ways to do this.

Comment: thank you very very very much, I understood now how you did it 
thanks :)